# using retrofit enqueue calls

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm new to android. I'm trying to make a call to a rest service with jwt.
Is there a better way to make these 2 calls?
Looks poorly written because the call to the service is attached to the jwt call and unless the jwt token is expired it shouldn't call that service every time, right?

Thanks in advance for your feedback

```
final GetDataService service = RetrofitClientInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(GetDataService.class);

        Call<Void> tokenCall = service.geToken(new AccountCredentials("admin", "password"));
        tokenCall.enqueue(new Callback<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Void> call, Response<Void> response) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                token = response.headers().get("Authorization");

                Call<List<Event>> eventCall = service.getAllEvents(token);
                eventCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<Event>>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<List<Event>> call, Response<List<Event>> response) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        generateDataList(response.body());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<List<Event>> call, Throwable t) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something went wrong...Please try later!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Void> call, Throwable t) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something went wrong...Please try later!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

it's a good solution. but you can enhance the design of code by writing the second call in a new method and just call the method.

the better solution is to using the RXJAVA see

https://medium.com/@adinugroho/chaining-multiple-retrofit-call-using-rxjava-177b64c8103e

https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/a-mvp-approach-to-lifecycle-safe-requests-with-retrofit-20-and-rxjava

https://medium.com/@mtrax/rxandroid-2-with-retrofit-2-and-gson-3f08d4c2627d